# How can I write javascript like this ruby code (array matching)?

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays

This is my ruby code.

```
array1= [1,2,3,4,5]
array2= [2,3,4,5,6]
if (array1 & array2).size == 4
   puts "4 match"
```

How can I write the same thing in javascript? Is there any material like ruby-doc in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a native method do do it.
Have a look at here : [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

The best documentation I know about javascript and html5 is the [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).